# Why inline assembly doesn't work with ARC in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, automatic-ref-counting, llvm, inline-assembly

I am really confused with this subject. I am using LLVM 4.1 compiler on Xcode and when I compile  a simple basic code like this in 32 bit or x64 or x64-x86 mode with ARC off, everything is ok
but if I compile with Automatic Reference Counting mode; I receive `BAD_ACCESS` error.

This is a sample code:

```
-(void) doNothing{

__asm__ volatile(
             "pushl %ebp;"
             "movl %esp , %ebp ;" 
             "movl %eax , -4(%ebp);"
             "movl %ebp, %esp;"
             "popl %ebp;"
             "leave;" 
             "ret  "    // retl in x86
             );

}
```

I tried to figure out the source of error I found that the push/pops are the only parts that work in ARC mode!

It is so frustrating because I have written a huge code in past in inline assembly and now I have to joint it to a module with ARC. Now if I can't solve it , I may need to revise all that module for working without ARC !

Can anyone help me on that?

Comment: `ARC in XCode`?? in Wrong, XCode is just an Editor like AppCode. Your qustion should be in `Arc in Cocoa`.

Comment: you are right. ARC in Cocoa .

Comment: Well... if we're nitpicking, ARC is actually an ObjC feature, not a Cocoa feature. Refcounting is implemented in libobjc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use ARC in 32-bit mode on OS X. According to the [Objective-C Feature Availability Index](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/_index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012243), ARC requires a 64 system on OS X.

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a solution, but provided you can't fix it, you can move the problematic methods' implementation into a category and compile just that category with -fno-objc-arc. That way your objc code remains arc'ed and you get your assembler working

Comment: Thanks. but unfortunately I have recently moved from visual studio into Xcode. I dont know where I should access the compiler settings for setting to -fno-objc-arc. I would appreciate if you could help me on that

Comment: Click on the project (top left, blue thing), then select your target on the right, build phases, Compile sources. Double click on the file you want to de-arc, and -fno-objc-arc it :)

Comment: The same problem !  but at least I learned to work with Xcode compiler. thanks for that.   I think something is wrong with my code.It seems that after the line   "movl %esp , %ebp ;"  the ARC loses the primary stack pointer address. can you have a look at the code itself please?

Comment: I haven't written assembly since 2009 and I was never that well versed. Sorry, I'm useless to you for that haha.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest trying to put assembler code in C or C++ function, not the ObjC message. And adding `__attribute__((naked))` to function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution but dont know why it works!! I will give the point of answer to whom can explain it. I realized that the main cause of problem is related to x64 behaviour of ARC. So I changed the code &deleted the lines "leave" and "ret" and now it works but I dont know : 1- why ARC behaves like x64 even in x86 mode and 2- why I had to omit "leave" and "ret"new code:

```
             "pushq %rbp;"
             "movq %rsp , %rbp ;"
             "movl %eax , -4(%rbp);"
             "popq %rbp;"
             );
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ARC in x86 mode"? According to the [Objective-C Feature Availability Index](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/_index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012243), ARC requires a 64 system on OS X.

Comment: thanks   I didn't know that    .   you could put it as an answer instead of a comment that I could mark it as correct answer.